# python - sklearn Latent Dirichlet Allocation Transform v. Fittransform

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn's NMF and LDA sub-modules to analyze unlabeled text. I read the documentation but I am not sure if the transform functions in these modules (NMF and LDA) are the same as the posterior function in R's topicmodels (please see [Predicting LDA topics for new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115102/predicting-lda-topics-for-new-data)). Basically, I am looking for a function that will allow me to predict the topics in test set using the model trained on training set data. I predicted topics on the entire dataset. Then I split the data into train and test sets, trained a model on train set and transformed test set using that model. though it was expected that I would not get the same results, comparing the two runs topics is not assuring me that the transform function serves the same function as R's package. I would appreciate your response.

thank you

Comment: what scikit-learn version are you using?

Comment: also, what indicated that results are different?

Comment: thank you Mikhail, v 0.18. my goal to understand if the transform function does provide the functionality to predict the topics in a test set. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The call to `transform` on a `LatentDirichletAllocation` model returns an *unnormalized document topic distribution*. To get proper probabilities, you can simply normalize the result. Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import numpy as np

# grab a sample data set
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(shuffle=True, remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
train,test = dataset.data[:100], dataset.data[100:200]

# vectorizer the features
tf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=25)
X_train = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(train)

# train the model
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=5)
lda.fit(X_train)

# predict topics for test data
# unnormalized doc-topic distribution
X_test = tf_vectorizer.transform(test)
doc_topic_dist_unnormalized = np.matrix(lda.transform(X_test))

# normalize the distribution (only needed if you want to work with the probabilities)
doc_topic_dist = doc_topic_dist_unnormalized/doc_topic_dist_unnormalized.sum(axis=1)
```

To find the top ranking topic you can do something like:

```
doc_topic_dist.argmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan, something that I was thinking: NMF model, and LDA I believe at least, lda module (not sklearn), produces two matrices W and H. Would it be ok to predict test data set by first  X_test = tf_vectorizer.transform(test) and then X_test*H.T?